# In CrossUI, how to force return of dimensions in spite of "auto"

Tags: javascript, web-frameworks

The CrossUI RAD ui-builder has recently undergone major restructuring. The UI widgets now default at "em" dimensions, and more of the widgets (buttons, primarily, I think) have default widths and heights set to "auto" unless you force dimensions on them.
My question is, how can I get the dimensions of a specific ui control if it is set to "auto"? If I use this code:

```
h=profile.boxing().getHeight();
```

It returns "auto", but I'd like to get the height dimension, either in em or px - doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks as though you can do

```
profile.getRoot().height();
```

and it seems to work to return subpixel pixel dimensions, with a float; I can round it.